# Are the power mean inequalities still valid when they are generalized to continuous functions?

Tags: average, means

I need to measure a mean value of a function $f(\mathbf{x})\geq0$ defined over a domain $\Omega$.

It would be very useful to me to be able to parametrize this mean value so that:

$$M_{-\infty}(f)=\min\limits_{\Omega}(f)$$
$$M_{\infty}(f)=\max\limits_{\Omega}(f)$$
$$p < q \Rightarrow M_p(f) \leq M_q(f)$$

---

Well, [power means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean) have these properties, but they are defined for discrete data:

$$M_p(k_1,...,k_n) = \left[\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} k_i^p\right]^{\frac{1}{p}}$$

$$M_0(k_1,...,k_n) = \lim_{p\rightarrow0}M_p(k_1,...,k_n) = \left[\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n}k_i\right]^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

---

By generalizing this to the continuous case, I believe we would have:

$$M_p(f) = \left[\frac{1}{V(\Omega)}\int_{\Omega}f(\mathbf{x})^p\,dV\right]^{\frac{1}{p}}$$

Does this have the desired properties? What would be the expression for $M_0(f)$? Does this integral power mean have a name? I am having trouble in searching for references about it, everything I find is about the discrete case.

---

EDIT: Well, although I am still not sure about the other properties, I tried to obtain the expression of $M_0(f)$.

$$M_p(f) = \exp\left(\log\left(M_p(f)\right)\right) = \exp\left(\frac{1}{p}\left[\log\left(\int_\Omega f(\mathbf{x})^p\,dV\right) - \log\left(V(\Omega)\right)\right]\right)$$

The following limit can be simplified using the [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule): $$\lim_{p\rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{p}\left[\log\left(\int_\Omega f(\mathbf{x})^p\,dV\right) - \log\left(V(\Omega)\right)\right] = \lim_{p\rightarrow 0} \frac{d}{dp}\left[\log\left(\int_\Omega f(\mathbf{x})^p\,dV\right)\right] =\\= \lim_{p\rightarrow 0} \left[\frac{1}{\displaystyle \int_\Omega f(\mathbf{x})^p\,dV}\,\int_\Omega \log(f(\mathbf{x}))\,f(\mathbf{x})^p\,dV\right] = \frac{1}{V(\Omega)}\,\int_\Omega \log(f(\mathbf{x}))\,dV =\\= M_1(\log(f))$$

Therefore, $\boxed{M_0(f) = \exp(M_1(\log(f)))}$.

I had stated that: "If the expression is valid, it seems to me that, if exists $\mathbf{x_0} \in \Omega$ such that $f(\mathbf{x_0}) = 0$, then all means with $p\leq 0$ will be the same: $M_{-\infty} = ... = M_{-2}(f) = M_{-1}(f) = M_{0}(f) = \min\limits_{\Omega}(f) = 0$.". However, I see now that this is not true.

For example, it seems that $f(x) = |x|^n$, with $n>0$, will have $M_{p} = 0$ in any domain containing the origin only for $p \leq -1/n$. It seems that for a single point $\mathbf{x_0} \in \Omega$ such that $f(\mathbf{x_0}) = 0$ to be enough to all means with $p\leq 0$ be $0$, $f$ would have to be [flat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_function) in $\mathbf{x_0}$.

Still, I am not sure if the inequalities are valid for a function which can be $0$ at some point. So I add to the original question: are these properties valid for a function $f(\mathbf{x})\geq0$ defined over a domain $\Omega$?

Comment: Strongly related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thank you for your comment. I understand there is a relation with measures. However it is not clear to me if the inequalities are still valid when considering the average value (dividing by $V^{\frac{1}{p}}$). I mean, $M_p \leq M_q$ when $p<q$. Moreover, it is not clear to me if this is well defined for any value of $p$ ranging from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, usually I find restrictions like $p\geq 1$, so the ingregral can be seen as a norm.

Comment: Both true, which is why I only said it was strongly related, rather directly applying to your question. But this relation isn't so much about "measure" as just summing $p$-th powers. Measure is just a means of defining that summation.

Comment: So the properties are valid? Could you write an answer with some references or demonstrations?

Comment: My apologies. I meant that both of your concerns are real issues. I don't have immediate answers for them. Though the reason we don't talk about $L^p$ spaces for $p < 1$ is that $\|\cdot\|_p$ ceases to be a norm, which is not an issue for your question.